# For a typical broadband ISP, are nodes on the same subnet routed together or are they bridged?

Tags: networking, routing, switch, isp, network-topology

For a typical broadband ISP, are nodes on the same subnet routed together or are they bridged?

In other words, what kind of path will a packet take when going from one node on a subnet to another for a typical broadband ISP like COMCAST? Possibilities:

1) nodes are on the same LAN and are hubbed/routed so the NIC on each node sees every packet generated on the subnet

2) nodes are switched; each node sees only its own packets and those from the switch; packets to another node on the same subnet are switched directly to the other node

3) nodes are bridged to some kind of NOC/IDS before they are routed back to the subnet; in this case a packet might go through a bunch of machines before returning to the subnet

I tried doing a tracert to other nodes on my subnet. This was the result:

```
Tracing route to pool-173-76-15-213.bstnma.fios.verizon.net [173.76.15.201]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1     3 ms     4 ms     4 ms  L100.BSTNMA-VFTTP-145.verizon-gni.net [71.126.250.1]
  2    11 ms    12 ms    12 ms  pool-173-76-15-213.bstnma.fios.verizon.net [173.76.15.213]
```

So, by this test, it seems packets just go to the switch and then directly to the other node (option 2 above).

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem that spawned this question?

Comment: I think part of it also depends greatly on what kind of broadband it is. Is it fiber to the premesis? PPPoE? ATM? Cable/DOCSIS?